# ic_media_stop missing in @android:drawable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

Trying to use android:drawable/ic_media_stop in  project but apparently is the only one missing.

If I write it gives me the preview.

But, if I debug gives me it's private.

Can't find anywhere to download it.

Can anyone suggest how to solve it or where to download it.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Download what? Question doesn’t currently make sense. If you reference a drawable that doesn’t exist, then you need to define it in some appropriate android xaml file. Since you don’t show any code, there’s nothing more to say. Why do you expect it to exist? What do you expect it to be? Where did you get whatever code you are trying to run? What drawables do exist, and where did they come from?

Answer (score 0):

From the code `android:drawable/ic_media_stop` you shared, we could find that you want to refer to the image(`ic_media_stop`) icon from android system.

I did a test and I found I could only refer to the following images prefixed with `ic_media_`:

[image]

If you want to refer to the special image, you can put the image(e.g.`test.png`) into folder `drawable` and refer to it as follows:

```
  <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="60dp"  
    android:layout_height="60dp" 
    android:contentDescription="img"
    android:src="@drawable/test" />
```